# How to parse json data python django?

Tags: python, django, json

I have JSON data, I want to parse it.

I used Code bellow:

```
def json_update(request):
     j = urllib2.urlopen('http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/get_latest_verification')
     j_obj = json.load(j) 
     print j_obj.status
     return HttpResponse(j_obj.status)
```

But I am getting the error:

**AttributeError at /json_update**

'list' object has no attribute 'status'

my json data:

```
[{"status": "Registered", "credential": "10000323xsds", "scan_time": "Jan.15,2014, 03:30 pm", "asset_code": "cls103", "emp_id": "LS07", "location": "BLR-10", "auth_code": "DSC(Verisign", "operator": "pradeep", "id": 538}]
```

what is the correct way of parsing json data.

But when I updated the code to:

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
def json_update(request):
     j = urllib2.urlopen('http://ec2-72-44-51-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/get_latest_verification')
     j_obj = json.load(j)
     for jo in j_obj: 
      print j_obj[jo]['status']
     return HttpResponse(j_obj[jo]['status'])
```

I am getting error:

**TypeError at /json_update**

list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: Problem is not with json parsing. if you did j_obj[0]['status'] then it would work just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say your json data is:

```
[{"status": "Registered", "credential": "10000323xsds", "scan_time": "Jan.15,2014, 03:30 pm", "asset_code": "cls103", "emp_id": "LS07", "location": "BLR-10", "auth_code": "DSC(Verisign", "operator": "pradeep", "id": 538}]
```

This means when you do `j_obj = json.load(j)` your `j_obj` is a *list*. (Note the `[ ]` on the outside). That is why when you did `print j_obj.status` you got the error *"'list' object has no attribute 'status'"*

Your updated code does:

```
for jo in j_obj: 
    print j_obj[jo]['status']
```

This is the wrong way to use a `for _ in _` loop in Python, you are doing it like you would in Javascript. In Python you would write it like this:

```
for jo in j_obj: 
    print jo['status']
```

This will loop through items in the outer list (you have a single item, which is a dict) and print the `'status'` key of that dict.

You can see the `for _ in _` loop gives you the *actual item* from the list you're looping over, not an index. So in your case `jo` is a dict, this is why you were getting the error *"list indices must be integers, not dict"* when you tried to do `j_obj[jo]`.

See tutorial here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

You should access the `status` as a dictionary item, not as an attribute.
And the dictionary is an item of a list.

So the `print`, `return` statements should read as:

```
print j_obj[0]['status']
return HttpResponse(j_obj[0]['status'])
```

**UPDATE**

To print all key, value pairs:

```
for key, value in j_obj[0].items():
    print key, value
return HttpResponse('\n'.join( # OR   '<br>'.join
    '{} {}'.format(key, value)
    for key, value in j_obj[0].items()
))
```

Comment: yup all key value pairs...I updated the code u please check that also